# Excluding category from WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm trying to display a featured post on a custom "Class" taxonomy's archive page, and want to exclude posts in the categories with the slug "work" and "extra". The following isn't excluding those categories:

```
$class = get_queried_object(); // Get the current class
$current_class = $class->term_id; //Get the current class ID
$extras_cat = get_cat_ID( 'extra' );
$class_work_cat = get_cat_ID( 'work' );

$args = array(
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'filmbites_class',
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => $current_class,
        ),
      ),
      'category__not_in' => array( $extras_cat, $class_work_cat ),
      'posts_per_page' => 1
    );

$posts= new WP_Query($args);

if($posts->have_posts()) :
  while($posts->have_posts()) :
      $posts->the_post();
      $featured_post = get_the_ID(); //get the ID of the post to be featured
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I assumed it meant I needed to use the category ID, hence my use of the get_cat_ID() function. 

But I tested using the category IDs directly instead, and it worked. 

That led me to realize I was using get_cat_ID() wrong, as I was using the slugs rather than the category name. Using the category name worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `get_cat_ID()` function wrong. Used slugs instead of the category name.